# Get mac address for alive interface

Tags: linux, networking

Iam trying to get the mac_address for the interface which is up till now iam able to get this

`ifconfig | grep HWaddr`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:BE:94:24:41:62
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:BE:94:24:41:63
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:BE:94:24:41:64
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:BE:94:24:41:65
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9A:BE:94:24:41:61
```

Is there any one line command to get the mac_address for the interface link which is up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address`

`ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}'` prints your default interface name. Then you get your mac from `/sys/class/net/IFACE_NAME/address`

Answer (score 1):

You can try these solutions:

- For interfaces which are Up Use `ifconfig` with a Regular Expression for MAC 
  pattern:

`ifconfig  | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'`

- Some OS like CentOS doesn't provide `ifconfig`, so you can use `ip` like this:

`ip add | grep link/ether | awk '{print $2}'`

- For all interfaces you can just simply: `cat /sys/class/net/*/address`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the mac address of your interface. If you check the interface name and the MAC address are the first and last fields on a line with no leading whitespace.

```
ifconfig -a |
awk '/^[a-z]/ { iface=$1; mac=$NF; next }
    /inet addr:/ { print iface, mac }'
```

or very simplistic, you can use this

```
cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address
```

this actually return: bc:f8:6b:bd:55:00 (sample macaddress of the eth0)