# Get mac address in bash script (CRON)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sh

I am writing a script which will run on CRON DAILY

my-script.sh  has following content :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mac=$(cat /sys/class/net/$((ip route show default || /usr/sbin/ip route show default )|  awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address 2>&1 )
echo "$mac" >> /tmp/test.txt
```

Command Link : [Get mac address for alive interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512536/get-mac-address-for-alive-interface/43512673)

so when i run

```
bash my-script.sh
```

I get proper mac address in file test.txt

but when i set cron for same  (1 1 * * * bash my-script.sh > test.log 2>&1)
its giving me

```
my-script.sh: line 3: ip: command not found
my-script.sh: line 3: /usr/sbin/ip: No such file or directory
```

its not able to resolve

```
$((ip route show default || /usr/sbin/ip route show default )|  awk '/default/ {print $5}')
```

Comment: Maybe `awk` isn't in your default path? You could add a `* * * * * env>/tmp/crontab_env` cronjob temporarly to check the environment (in particular the $PATH) your script will be executed with.

Comment: I have updated the logs

Comment: the first error (ip: command not found) is expected by your script, it's why it contains the second command with an absolute path for the ip command. The problem we see with the second error is that path doesn't correspond to anything on your system. Check what `which ip` returns with your usual user and use that in the script

Comment: but its working when script is running without CRON ?

Comment: I mean i got it i have to chagne /usr/sbin/ip to /sbin/ip. but why IP command failing for CRON ?

Comment: Because the first command returns with success, so the second is never executed. `(ip route show default || /usr/sbin/ip route show default )` means "run the command `ip` (resolved from the `$PATH`), if that doesn't work run the command `/usr/sbin/ip`. When you execute it with your user `ip` is found in the `$PATH` and the `/usr/sbin/ip` command is never executed, but when you run with crontab and its default env it's not found in the default `$PATH` and neither at the /usr/sbin/ip location

Comment: For security reasons the `PATH` is minimal for `cron` jobs. Provide full path of your commands or add a proper `PATH` definition to your `crontab` file.

Comment: ohhk got it thanks